# Google picker api to force to show the account chooser page, if i already logged into the multiple Gmail Accounts

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-oauth, google-picker

I'm using [Google Picker Api](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) to accessing the Google drive files, working fine.

But in my browser if i already logged in to multiple Gmail accounts, automatically it is showing drive files from one account. Instead of this, is there a way to show the account chooser page, if already i have already logged in to the multiple Gmail accounts.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is only normal since your session hasn't expired yet. I think you have to implement logout or [revoke access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) for you to see that select accounts page again.